# How to validate a Youtube video & playlist url until they completely match or has a redirect to the video or playlist in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, url, youtube, pytube

I'm working on a small Youtube video & playlist downloader. However currently I'm facing a problem where I cannot validate the Youtube URL.

I bind "ReleaseKey" on the entrybox so everytime a user type, it checks if the url is valid or not and returns true or false. Here is how I implement the check:

```
req = requests.get(self.yt_url_string, allow_redirects=False)
if req.status_code == 200:
   print("True")
   return True
print("False")
return False
```

This check is kind of working fine if the user completely paste an actual valid url, however  if the user pastes half of the link like this [uncomplete link example](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2rTmCt6) it will still return true, then when the condition returns true it goes to pytube function which is
YouTube(url_from_the_user) and shows an error exception.

Is there any solution to validate the url or any other method to prevent from getting error exception message?

Comment: Instead of your five last lines, note that you can also do `is_status_code_200 = req.status_code == 200\nprint(is_status_code_200)\nreturn is_status_code_200`

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Many thanks for the advice. Even though this is not a fix for my problem, your suggestion has helped me to realize how to write short codes in a different approach. :)